# numpy.linalg.inv(M) much slower on one system than another

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

On my laptop, the following code takes only 3ms. On my cluster compute server it takes about 10s for over a 1000x slowdown. Why? And how can I fix it?

```py
import numpy
mat = numpy.random.random((150,150))
%timeit numpy.linalg.inv(mat)
```

I checked `numpy.show_config()` and get the following results. On the fast laptop:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    library_dirs = ['D:\\a\\1\\s\\numpy\\build\\openblas_info']
    libraries = ['openblas_info']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['D:\\a\\1\\s\\numpy\\build\\openblas_info']
    libraries = ['openblas_info']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    library_dirs = ['D:\\a\\1\\s\\numpy\\build\\openblas_lapack_info']
    libraries = ['openblas_lapack_info']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['D:\\a\\1\\s\\numpy\\build\\openblas_lapack_info']
    libraries = ['openblas_lapack_info']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

and on the slow server:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

I'm not really sure how to read these as its not documented, but they seem comparable except for the `language` setting. I tried changing to use Fortran-ordered arrays and there's no major impact.

Edit: running `import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo` and `sysinfo.get_info('openblas')` gives the following. On the fast laptop:

```
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable DF
Could not locate executable efl
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
```

On the slow server:

```
{'libraries': ['openblas', 'openblas'],
 'library_dirs': ['/usr/lib64'],
 'language': 'c',
 'define_macros': [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
```

Comment: I don't know about numpy on clusters, so apologies for the possibly noob question, but your code will run in the entire cluster, or just one node?

Comment: Can you check the CPU usage during the computation of both systems so to check if multiple cores used (and how much are they)? I expect one to be parallel and not the other (or barely). Alternatively, one possible issue is the thread over-subscription. A last possible issue is the use of parallelism to perform a small amount of work in a loop with a lot of iteration. The last is the most probable. By the way: do you have the MKL installed on your cluster?

Comment: @ArthurJulião Good question. It's just running the command on one PC.

Comment: @JérômeRichard On the fast case, running it repeatedly in a loop does show high CPU usage on all cores. On the slow case, it maxes out at 100% CPU in top, which I think means just one core. But I can't imagine that explains more than a factor of 8 (the number of cores no the laptop) of the slowdown. I don't know about MKL (unfortunately the cluster appears to have gone down right now.) I'm not sure I understand what you mean with your last, most probable issue.

Comment: I've now found that in another python environment on that cluster, it runs even faster than on my laptop and show_config() lists several SIMD extensions I guess I can solve this by changing to that version, but I'm still curious how anything could cause such a dramatic slowdown.

Comment: Ok. Can you update the question with the result of the execution of `import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo` followed by `sysinfo.get_info('openblas')` on both? Another point: can you run your Python command using `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE yourPythonCommand` and reports what is printed? The first print information how OpenBLAS is compiled and the second print information about the OpenMP parallel environment. By the way: are you running your code on an IBM machine (eg. AC922)?

Comment: @tgbrooks I would guess that your code is running on a single node, and that the node itself is weaker than your laptop

Comment: I've added that data to the question. Both machines are Intel processors. I don't see anything new printed from after doing using `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE ipython` and running the commands again.

Comment: Your numpy is just wrapping openblas for this, and you can absolutely compile openblas in ways that are glacially slow. I wouldn't overthink this - it's probably just compiled with no openmp support and poor optimization.